# Html: em tag character overflowing bug

Tags: html, background-color, italic

Is there a workaround for the character overflow issue in html? This is only visible when there is a background-color and italic (em) tag is used for simple text.

[image]

Look for the "i" character when background in the picture. "i" did not fit in the background and has some of its portion overflowed onto right.

Code:

```
    aaaaa<em style="color:#ff0000;background-color:#c3ddfc;">hijyen bariyeri</em>, aaaaaaa
```

Comment: perhaps `padding-right: 1em`?

Comment: what if font size is changed then?

Comment: doesn't matter. `em` is relative to font-size. it's always "the width of an `M` of the font/size being used".

Comment: i think you can set it inline-block and use padding or use &nbsp;

Comment: @MarcB, `em` is equal to the font size, but it is nowhere near the width of “M” (just measure the width of “M” to see this). And a padding of `1em` is far too much for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature, not a bug. The box of an element (which is what gets colored when you set a background color) is determined in a manner that does not account for the slanting of italic letters, for example. You can handle this by setting right padding, as @MarcB suggests in a comment, but there are complications. First, the amount of padding needed does not depend only on the font size (this dependence can be dealt with using the `em` unit) but also on the specific font face. The slanting angle varies by font design quite a lot, and so do the shapes of characters—e.g., slanting “f” has a much greater effect than slanting “e”. Second, when you add spacing after a letter followed by punctuation mark, as in the example, the word and the mark get separated in a typographically unpleasant way.

I would suggest thus that you include the punctuation mark inside the element; this might look illogical (the comma is not part of the emphasized expression), but it is typographically adequate. Quite often, this is sufficient for solving the problem. Example:

```
Özetle <em style=
"color:#ff0000; background-color:#c3ddfc;"
>hijyen bariyeri,</em> hiye
```

If the italicized word is not followed by a punctuation but a normal word space, consider setting right padding of about 0.2em, but decide on the specific value after some testing. Example:

```
Özetle <em style=
"color:#ff0000; background-color:#c3ddfc; padding-right: 0.2em"
>hijyen bariyeri</em> hiye
```

A value of 0.2em is typically suitable for fonts like Arial. For a font with no italic typeface, forcing browsers to produce “fake italic”, a value like 0.3em might be needed, since such synthetic slanting (which might be applied in your example) uses a large slanting angle to compensate for the lack of true italic. For a serif font, say Cambria or Times New Roman, 0.1em might be sufficient for most characters.